# Can the car jack get adjusted?

Tags: wheels, kia, jack, jack-stand

I was lifting my car (Kia Sportage) with its jack

when I get it down I noticed the Jack was twisted as in this photo
[image]

[image]

not sure if it is broken or it just adjusted.

Can someone tell me if it is fixable, how?

Answer (score 17):

The gear mechanism skipped a tooth. It's likely broken and dangerous to use.

Such jacks are quite cheap; in Norway they are available for 20-25USD, so I would simply pick up a new one, or raise a warranty claim against the manufacturer. I would *not* attempt to repair it.

Comment: I would shell out another 10 USD to get a cheap hydraulic bottle jack -- way less hassle to use.

Comment: Almost without exception, the jack that comes with the car is a piece of junk.  It's the bare minimum required by the safety standards that say every car must come with a jack.  Better than nothing when you're stuck on the side of the road with a flat, but basically worthless for anything else.